# Adding a meta tag via jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-7

I need to add this meta-tag in the head section of the page as i need the page to force IE7.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />
```

I am using DNN 5.6

How can i do this?

Comment: I'm not sure whether IE will react to this if you add it dynamically. Why not add it on server side?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`$('head').append('<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />
');`

Though I'm not certain it will have an affect as it will be generated after the page is loaded

-- edit --

> If you want to add meta data tags for page description, use the
>   SETTINGS of your DNN page to add Description and Keywords.  Beyond
>   that, the best way to go when modifying the HEAD is to dynamically
>   inject your code into the HEAD via a third party module.

Found at http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Forums/forumid/7/threadid/298385/scope/posts.aspx

This may allow other meta tags, if you're lucky

-- edit 2 --

> Additional HEAD tags can be placed into Page Settings > Advanced
>   Settings > Page Header Tags.

Found at http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Forums/forumid/-1/postid/223250/scope/posts.aspx

Comment: Hopefully! For info, I found this with a Google search for `dotnetnuke head add meta`

Answer (score 2):

There is really no use in adding `<meta>` headers after the page has loaded.

To force IE7 rendering, change the underlying HTML.

Comment: how do i force my skin file to load ie7?

Comment: @PD24: I am not sure what You mean by "skin" and "load ie7".