# How to add meta tag in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, meta-tags

I want to add `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">` for a particular page.

But my pages are rendered inside one `HTML` tag. Only the content is changing on clicking different templates. So i cannot add the `<meta>` in `<HEAD>` section.

Is there any way to add the `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">` using `javascript` ?

Comment: You can't do meta tags with JavaScript. You  can add the tag to the template or you can set the header from the HTTP server.

Comment: I believe this has been answered here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7063863/adding-a-meta-tag-via-jquery

Comment: @Dontfeedthecode I seriously doubt that that answer actually works.

Comment: @Dontfeedthecode: And relies on jQuery, which this question doesn't mention.

Answer (score 93):

You can add it:

```
var meta = document.createElement('meta');
meta.httpEquiv = "X-UA-Compatible";
meta.content = "IE=edge";
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta);
```

...but I wouldn't be surprised if by the time that ran, the browser had already made its decisions about how to render the page.

The real answer here has to be to output the correct tag from the server in the first place. (Sadly, you can't just not have the tag if you need to support IE. :-| )

Comment: I can confirm that adding the meta tag dynamically doesn't work in IE8.

Comment: I've been able to force *Quirks* instead of *IE 7 Standards* by replacing the whole document content using `document.write`. Perhaps there's a way to create a new document object in IE8 and replace the current document with that new one, which hopefully will trigger a reevaluation of the document mode. The `createDocument` function isin't available in IE8, but I guess we could rely on an `iframe` to create a new document instance.

Comment: IE sucks.No use of this in IE because as soon as page rendering is started n thing is specified or there is a conflict IE take a stand in favor the dead man i.e. IE7.

Comment: Can I use `document.head.appendChild()` instead?

Comment: @marcellothearcane - If your browser supports it, yes. I think all modern ones do.

Answer (score 23):

```
$('head').append('<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />');
```

or

```
var meta = document.createElement('meta');
meta.httpEquiv = "X-UA-Compatible";
meta.content = "IE=edge";
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta);
```

Though I'm not certain it will have an affect as it will be generated after the page is loaded

> If you want to add meta data tags for page description, use the
> SETTINGS of your DNN page to add Description and Keywords.  Beyond
> that, the best way to go when modifying the HEAD is to dynamically
> inject your code into the HEAD via a third party module.

Found at http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Forums/forumid/7/threadid/298385/scope/posts.aspx

This may allow other meta tags, if you're lucky

> Additional HEAD tags can be placed into Page Settings > Advanced
> Settings > Page Header Tags.

Found at http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Forums/forumid/-1/postid/223250/scope/posts.aspx

Answer (score 11):

Like this ?

```
<script>
var meta = document.createElement('meta');
meta.setAttribute('http-equiv', 'X-UA-Compatible');
meta.setAttribute('content', 'IE=Edge');
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta);
</script>
```

Comment: You don't need `setAttribute` for this, both `httpEquiv` and `content` are [reflected](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#the-meta-element).

Answer (score 8):

As specified by @marcellothearcane, for modern browser, you can also use:

```
var meta = document.createElement('meta');
meta.httpEquiv = "X-UA-Compatible";
meta.content = "IE=edge";
document.head.appendChild(meta);
```

Supported browser here: [document.head](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/head)

Answer (score 2):

Try

```js
document.head.innerHTML += '<meta http-equiv="X-UA-..." content="IE=edge">'
```