# jQuery - input with special characters

Tags: jquery, special-characters

I am trying to set the `.val()` of a field with special characters, but it doesnt show the special characters in the input:

```
$( "input" ).val( "Justifique as propostas não escolhidas e insira observações para as escolhidas." );
```

this is my input:
[image]

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your document is using UTF8 encoding. Add this to your HTML `<head>`:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
```

Comment: I cant edit `<head>`. I can only use javascript. so I tryed this: $( "head" ).append( '<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>' ); but didnt work

Comment: Did you do that before or after this script? Also, is the script inline or externally loaded?

Comment: I did like this: <script type="text/javascript">
$( "head" ).append( '<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>' );</script>

Comment: Is that script before or after the `.val()` script? And is the `.val()` script inline or not? Because if it is, the special characters won't even be loaded there.

Comment: the script is before the `.val()` and it is not inline

Comment: The browser has likely already determined what mode to display the page in, and adding this `<meta>` tag dynamically with JavaScript after the browser has begun parsing the page [probably isn't going to change it](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18982299/1883647).