# Can I Add Meta Tags on page with Google Tag Manager?

Tags: google-tag-manager

I have added Tag Manager script on my page. So can I add more meta tags to my page.

I means can there will be Tag manager script and meta tags on page or from both of these I should use script or tags?

Thanks
Dalvir

Answer (score 6):

I assume you mean HTML meta tags like keywords, description etc.

You can add them via the tag manager by inserting a custom html/javascript tag that [creates additional meta tags via js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18982228/how-to-add-meta-tag-in-javascript) in the page header. **However** that will probably won't do you much good, as search engine spiders etc. will probably not pick up meta-tags that have been inserted via javascript and browsers are unlikely to respect tags that have been injected after the page started rendering.

So theoretically it'S possible, but I cannot conceive a use case where it would make sense.

Comment: While this was probably not effective when this answer was written, this article https://moz.com/blog/seo-changes-using-google-tag-manager suggests that the Google search engine spider now does digest changes made by the Javascript.

Answer (score 5):

I use this little badboy when I need to populate meta-tags, seems to work like a wee charm.

```
<script>
  var m = document.createElement('meta'); 
  m.name = 'your-name'; 
  m.content = 'your-content'; 
  document.head.appendChild(m);
</script>
```