# Modify DOM elements outside root component

Tags: internationalization, angular

My Angular 2 app is structured something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <base href="/" />

    <script src="jspm_packages/system.js"></script>
    <script src="config.js"></script>

    <script>
        System.import('client/main.js');
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <my-app></my-app>
</body>
</html>
```

The root component is the `my-app` component.

I would like to modify the `html` element which is outside the root component template to add some attributes to it. Is this possible?

In my case, I'm trying to set `dir` and `lang` attributes based on the current user's settings, which would be retrieved at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use normal [JS DOM access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18982228/how-to-add-meta-tag-in-javascript) or use the DOM adapter as shown in the [`Title` service](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/platform-browser/index/Title-class.html) ([source](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/browser/title.ts))

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#400-beta0-2016-12-15 also introduces a `Meta` service to create and modify `<meta>` tags.

Comment: The `Title` service example looks promising. Will try it out!

Comment: Yes, had a similar problem described in the GitHub issue above. Got something working by using `BrowserDomAdapter` from 'angular2/platform/browser'.  This article has some useful examples: `http://www.bennadel.com/blog/3052-injecting-html-with-the-browserdomadapter-in-angularjs-2-beta-9.htm`

Comment: There is better support planned but not sure when they'll find time to work on it. I tried to look up the related issue but wasn't able to find it.

Comment: Updated link https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/browser/title.ts

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I have posted a similar question, but its about accessing window object. Can you plz take a look it if you have some clarity in this area

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42671975/call-a-method-on-window-get-result-safely-in-angular-2