# Angular 2 - get window properties

Tags: angular

I can't find documentation and examples for this.

I need to have access to window properties, to get view port width, innerHeight and all the properties assigned. Any ideas ?

ty !

Comment: What is the problem? What have you tried? Let's see some code.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36157605/modify-dom-elements-outside-root-component/36157681#36157681

Comment: Actually my attempt: import {DOM} from 'angular2/src/platform/dom/dom_adapter'; - then: myFunc() { console.log(DOM.query('window')); } - and it's not working...Cannot read property 'query' of null

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`window.innerHeight` and similar or use `DOM` which is an abstraction to stay WebWorker- and server-side-rendering safe.

[Modify DOM elements outside root component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36157605/modify-dom-elements-outside-root-component/36157681#36157681)

You should be aware of github.com/angular/angular/issues/6904

Comment: ty ! But I really need an example..I saw the dom and browser-dom libs, but there is no example. Also , at https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/angular2/src/platform/dom/dom_adapter.ts there is nothing on the adapters that's suggests access to window. element - Or it's just me with no idea how to use because it's not much intuitive.

Comment: I know. There are no docs, no explanation when a how it should be used. Sometimes it's discouraged to use DOM. Of course, if there are other ways like global event binding `(window:keydown)` or similar, this should be used, but otherwise DOM is used by Angular code like the `Title` service mentioned in the linked answer. This just is not yet a beaten path.

Comment: I can use the title..there is implementation for this on DOM. But not for window :) I need to know how to grab my InnerHeight :( but tyvm , Gunter !

Comment: So, what's the problem with `window.innerHeight`?

Comment: Giizz, Gunter...I can use window.innerHeight with no restriction !!! I'm feeling in shame now :( Plz modify your answer so I can makr you as answered. (red face now)