# Angular 2: change DOM elements outside the root AppComponent

Tags: dom, angular, typescript, rxjs5

I have an observable -- `loading$` -- that outputs *true* when I want to show a loading overlay in the UI, and *false* when it's time to remove that overlay. The visibility is controlled with a CSS class.

When the Observable emits *true*, I want to add the CSS class to the `<body>`, and remove it on *false*.

**html**

```
<body class="">
    <my-app>Angular app goes here</my-app>
</body>
```

As you can see, the `<body>` is outside of my `Angular 2` app, so I cannot use property binding to change the class. This is what I currently do:

**AppComponent.ts**

```
loading$.subscribe(loading =>{
    if(loading) document.querySelector('body').classList.add('loading');
    else document.querySelector('body').classList.remove('loading');
});
```

This works well. The `loading` class is added/removed when the `loading$` observable emits *true*/*false*.  The problem is that I'd like to run my app in a web worker which means no access to the DOM. Plus, Angular recommends against manipulating the DOM directly.

How can I use `Angular` APIs to change `<body>`?

`Angular 2`, `typescript 2`, `rxjs 5 beta 12`

PS: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36157605/modify-dom-elements-outside-root-component) looks promising, but the key link is dead. I've also seen a couple of suggestions that worked with Beta releases but are now obsolete ([example](http://stackoverflow.duapp.com/questions/34432980/angular-2-x-selecting-dom-element?noredirect=1))

Comment: Angular allows you to change the [page title](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/set-document-title.html) only, when we speak about access to external elements towards Angular. Why it is important for you to manipulate DOM from outside? Why not make it within the `my-app`?

Comment: @ktretyak When `body` has `loading` class, a loading overlay is shown. `index.html` has the the class set ON by default. I want the webpage to display this loading overlay until it is ready for user input (until `Angular` root component is loaded). So once the component loads, I use `Angular` to remove the CSS class.  Likewise when users route away from a component, I enable `loading` on `CanDeactivate` hook, and disable it when the next route is loaded (in `OnInit` hook)

Comment: You can make root component is very lightweight (like `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`), and you do not have to wait when it is loading.

Comment: @ktretyak thanks for the idea. It could be my backup plan, but it's not great: For even a lightweight root component to load, all the Angular dependency libraries (coreJS, zoneJS, ReflectMetadata, SystemJS) as well as 3rd party libraries used by my root module (Angular 2 Material, CryptJS) need to be downloaded, and the bootstrapper needs to finish setting things up.  The purpose of my current implementation is to show the loading UI during all this process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do like this:

```
<my-app>
  <div class="your-class-for-loading"></div>
</my-app>
```

When `my-app` is ready, div will be automatically removed.

Comment: Thank you. You inspired me to a solution (I wrote it as an answer)

Answer (score 3):

If you want an uninterrupted animation by DOM replacement in the middle of bootstrapping the app then use the following approach.

Put the overlay after `my-app` element.

```
<my-app></my-app>
<div id="overlay"></div>
```

Add `@HostBinding` to `class.ready` in main component `app.component.ts`:

```
@HostBinding('class.ready') ready: boolean = false;
```

Change the property when the data is loaded with the initial call (splash is still visible when your screen is not fully rendered).

```
constructor(private contextService: ContextService) {
    someService.initCall().then(r => this.ready = true);
}
```

Use CSS to hide the loader:

```
my-app.ready + .overlay {
    animation: hideOverlay 1s forwards;
}

@keyframes hideOverlay {
  0% {
        opacity: 1;
  }

  100% {
        opacity: 0;
        visibility: hidden;
  }
}
```

Comment: Haven't tested this but it's really clever!

Answer (score 2):

@ktretyak 's solution got things to work for me. Basically, instead of using `<body>` I put the div that takes the `loading` class within `<my-app>`

**index.html**

```
<body>
    <my-app>
        <div id="overlay" class="loading"></div>
    </my-app>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
#overlay {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
    display:none;
}
#overlay.loading {
    display:block
}
```

Thanks to the CSS styles, and the fact that `loading` is enabled to start, the overlay is shown while the Javascript loads and `Angular` bootstraps.

Once `Angular` is loaded though, everything within `<my-app>` will be replaced with `AppComponent` template.  As I explained in the comments beneath the OP, I need ongoing access to this loading overlay, because I show it during the loading of new routes (as users navigate from one routed component to another). So I had to include the same overlay div in the template

**app.component.html**

```
<div id="overlay" [class.loading]="showLoading"></div>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Now, when my `loading$` observable fires, I change a class property `showLoading` and Angular takes care of updating the overlay since it is now part of `AppComponent`

**app.component.ts**

```
// set to true to show loading overlay. False to hide
showLoading:boolean = true;

ngOnInit(){
    // show/hide overlay depending on value emitted
    loading$.subscribe(loading => this.showLoading = loading);
}
```