# Call a method on window get result safely in angular 2+

Tags: angular, global-variables

Accessing computed style requires us to call the following method

`window.getComputedStyle(elementRef.nativeElement)`

The above method return `CssStyle` object, which we can use to access the computed properties such as padding set via css class/any native defaults.

AFAIK, in angular, invoking methods on global/native elements is prohibited due the fact the program may not work when we try to render it on the server side.

I know that we have `Renderer` to invoke methods on native elements, but the method signature does not return any result (has a `void` return type).

Is there a way to safely invoke a method on window & get result in Angular 2+?

Comment: Either don't access these browser objects or don't use server-side rendering or web worker features. Alternatively you can use DI to inject different abstractions depending on the platform where the code is executed. I don't know how to configure that because that's not available in Dart and I haven't tried in TS.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like I need to use hacks to check whether the given environment is browser or not

Comment: There should be examples. Perhaps check the universal GitHub repo. I ignored this topic so far.

Comment: Thanks. I'll check.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
 declare let window: any;
 @Component({
   selector: 'some',
   templateUrl: '<span>Content here</span>'
 })
 export class SomeComponent implements OnInit {
    ngOnInit(): void {
       if(window && window.getComputedStyle){
          // do staff here
       }
    }
 }
```

Comment: what if window is undefined?

Comment: :) Sorry for not making my point earlier. Renderer was created for this whole reason. You can access document aswell in the same way, but there are elegant solutions exist such as injecting DOCUMENT token into your constructor.

I was looking for solution of that sort. This works, but hacky. Thanks in anycase

Comment: there is another solution , using providers see the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40222084/how-to-inject-window-into-angular-2-1-0

Comment: Thank you for that. However, it has exactly the same problem, migration between environments