# How to add a meta tag into the document AFTER they hit yes on a confirm box

Tags: javascript, html

How do I add the meta refresh tag via js AFTER they click yes on the confirm box? Overall layout is...

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var metaRefreshConfirm = confirm("Do you want META Refresh?");
            if (metaRefreshConfirm === true)
            {
                //code here for meta refresh
            }
            else if (metaRefreshConfirm === false)
            {
                alert("META Refresh not applied");
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why add a `<meta>` refresh tag in this case? If you're using javascript anyway, just `setTimeout(function() { location.reload() }, 20*1000)`

Comment: To give guests a choice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it this way, create node and append it in the `head`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            var metaRefreshConfirm = confirm("Do you want META Refresh?");
            if (metaRefreshConfirm === true)
            {
               var meta = document.createElement('meta');
               meta.httpEquiv = "refresh" 
               meta.content = "30";// secs
               document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta);
            }
            else if (metaRefreshConfirm === false)
            {
                alert("META Refresh not applied");
            }
        </script>
```

Comment: Any idea on how to add a few tabs to make it organized with the rest?

Answer (score 1):

```
//code here for meta refresh
var meta = document.createElement("meta");
meta.setAttribute("http-equiv", "refresh");
meta.setAttribute("content", "5");
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(meta);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `append` function.

May answers of this question can help you. [How to add meta tag in javascript](http://May%20answers%20of%20this%20question%20can%20help%20you.%20[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18982228/how-to-add-meta-tag-in-javascript])