# In Eclipse Rap 4.0, how to add meta http-equiv in head

Tags: eclipse, content-security-policy, head, eclipse-rap, http-equiv

I'm trying to allow mixed content from an iframe in an Eclipse Rap application.
It should work using a http-equiv meta in an like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests"> 
</head>
<body>
<iframe src="http://erlend.oftedal.no/blog/tools/xframeoptions/"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

The eclipse developers-guide exemple works:

```
<additionalHeaders>
  <meta name="author" content="Arthur Dent">
  </meta>
</additionalHeaders>
```

(see https://eclipse.org/rap/developers-guide/devguide.php?topic=branding.html&version=2.0)

```
I wasn't successful when I added http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy:
<additionalHeaders>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests"></meta>
</additionalHeaders>
```

For deployment I use WildFly 10 with https enabled.

So my question are:

1. How can I enable mixed content on a Eclipse Rap Application?
2. How to add a meta tag in a Eclipse Rap Application?

Comment: When adding additional headers 
<additionalHeaders>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests"></meta>
</additionalHeaders>

in browser source only the content attribute appears without http-equiv: <meta content="upgrade-insecure-requests">

Comment: Following https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18982228/how-to-add-meta-tag-in-javascript I managed to add a meta in head, but when js runs, the browser started to load the iframe, so is no useful.