# How to add meta tag using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add meta tag in my site header using jQuery. How may I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This seems to have already been covered here - http://stackoverflow.com/a/7063880/2588199

Comment: Please search before posting, or in this case, just look at the list of questions the site specifically asked you if you'd already checked.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $("head").append("<meta name=viewport content=width=400, initial-scale=0.45, minimum-    scale=0.45/><link rel=apple-touch-icon href=/images/customIcon.png/><meta name=apple-mobile-web-app-capable content=no /><meta name=apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style content=black-translucent /><link rel=apple-touch-icon-precomposed href=/images/customIcon.png/> ");
});
```

Comment: I've used but it's not working for me.  :(

Answer (score -1):

```
 <script type="text/javascript"> 
 $(document).ready(function() {      

  $("meta[name='og:title']").attr('content', 'my new title');
 });
 </script>
```

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan I have edited my answer check now.